# Android: Detect ACTION_UP event outside button

Tags: java, android, android-animation, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I'm having some problem with a custom button I built. It consist of a box and a small line below it.

The button animates down vertically when you press on it and up again when you release. This is handled in the CustomButton.class:

```
super.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    buttonContent.startAnimation(rectMoveDown);
                    colorDown.start();
                    return false;
                }
                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    buttonContent.startAnimation(rectMoveUp);
                    colorUp.start();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Then in the rest of the application I use this button and set a clicklistener to it. Therefore I return false (I think that is correct at least) since I do not want to consume the event, but pass it on to the clicklistener in the hierarchy.

However, the problem emerge when I first press down on the button, move my finger outside the button and then release the screen. Then the button do not show the animation done in the ACTION_UP listener.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out how I could solve it after some more testing!

After reading some more in the documentation I found that [MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL) does exactly what I need:

> The current gesture has been aborted. You will not receive any more
>   points in it. You should treat this as an up event, but not perform
>   any action that you normally would.

So now my TouchListener look like this (and works like it should):

```
super.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        buttonContent.startAnimation(rectMoveDown);
                        colorDown.start();
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        buttonContent.startAnimation(rectMoveUp);
                        colorUp.start();
                        return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

It was not that I started to use the switch-case that solved it, but I changed to it in order to make the code look better. As you can see I handle the ACTION_UP and the ACTION_CANCEL in the exact same way.

I return false everywhere in order for the OnClickListener to trigger which it wouldn't if I returned true.

Comment: Thank you I had exactly the same problem with an animated switch button, which didn't work correctly when I touch up outside of its area. Now it works.